# getting Error running WSGI application NameError: while i deployed my DJango app to pythonanywhere?

Tags: python, django, pythonanywhere

**Complete error**

```
2021-09-18 10:35:44,065: Error running WSGI application
2021-09-18 10:35:44,068: NameError: name 'get_wsgi_application' is not defined
2021-09-18 10:35:44,068: File "/var/www/dhruv354_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py", line 30, in <module>
2021-09-18 10:35:44,068: application = get_wsgi_application()
```

**my wsgi.py file**

```
import os
import sys
path = '/home/dhruv354/Django-grocery/'
if path not in sys.path:
    sys.path.append(path)

os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'ReadingRight.settings'

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
from whitenoise.django import DjangoWhiteNoise
application = DjangoWhiteNoise(get_wsgi_application())
```

Everything seems fine to me but still it is giving this error, needs help

Comment: Is is correct wsgi file, because error indicated some different name in logs `/var/www/dhruv354_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py` and `application = get_wsgi_application()`

Comment: WSGI configuration file   :     /var/www/dhruv354_pythonanywhere_com_wsgi.py                           this is the correct name

Comment: Can you please check your virtual environment if Django is available by typing `python` and then `import django`

Comment: @SuyogShimpi I am suspecting that he might be facing a permission issue such as installing dependencies as a `root` because the code he listed should work fine out-of-box

Comment: Yes Django is available

Comment: Are you sure that you're looking at the right error in the error log?  I see that you have `from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application`, so the error `name 'get_wsgi_application' is not defined` does not make sense.  Perhaps there's another error message further down in the log file?  The most recent error will be at the bottom of the file.

Comment: Yah it is resolved i was just looking at the top to get the errors, i found the error scrolling down , please resolve the question